# PreloadAllModules cause ReferenceError: Cannot access 'myModule' before initialization

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-routing, angular-module

[USING: Angular 8, Chrome79, Ionic 4, dev mode (ionic serve)]

I have an issue with my Angular Router, I have enabled `PreloadAllModules` and depending which module come first in my routes definition it will cause `ReferenceError: Cannot access 'myModule' before initialization` to the other.

```js
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from "@angular/router";

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    pathMatch: "full",
    redirectTo: "home"
  },
  {
    loadChildren: () => import("./home/home.module").then((m) => m.HomePageModule),
    path: "home"
  },
  {
    loadChildren: () => import("./list/list.module").then((m) => m.ListPageModule),
    path: "list"
  },
  {
    loadChildren: () =>
      import("./myFirstModule/app/myFirstModule.module").then((m) => m.MyFirstModule),
    path: "myFirstModule"
  },
  {
    loadChildren: () =>
      import("./mySecondModule/app/mySecondModule.module").then((m) => m.mySecondModule),
    path: "mySecondModule"
  }
];

@NgModule({
  exports: [RouterModule],
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

The above code will fire : `ReferenceError: Cannot access 'mySecondModule' before initialization` when clicking on the link in my menu, BUT the error will not fire if I access the route directly by URL !

If I intervert `myFirstModule` and `mySecondModule` like so :

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    pathMatch: "full",
    redirectTo: "home"
  },
  {
    loadChildren: () => import("./home/home.module").then((m) => m.HomePageModule),
    path: "home"
  },
  {
    loadChildren: () => import("./list/list.module").then((m) => m.ListPageModule),
    path: "list"
  },
  {
    loadChildren: () =>
      import("./mySecondModule/app/mySecondModule.module").then((m) => m.mySecondModule),
    path: "mySecondModule"
  },
  {
    loadChildren: () =>
      import("./myFirstModule/app/myFirstModule.module").then((m) => m.MyFirstModule),
    path: "myFirstModule"
  }
];
```

The error will fire on navigation to `myFirstModule` : `ReferenceError: Cannot access 'myFirstModule' before initialization` but it will work if I access directly via URL ....

If I remove PreloadAllModules I can navigate a first time to any module, but then when I access the other module I get an error of my libraries : 
`ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined at sax.js:222`

**myFirstModule**

```js
export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient): TranslateHttpLoader {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, "./assets/i18n/", ".json");
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyFirstModuleComponent,
    ...
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    ...
  ],
  exports: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    IonicModule,
    MyMaterialModule,
    MyStore1Module,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        component: MyFirstModuleComponent,
        path: ""
      }
    ]),
    TranslateModule.forChild({
      loader: {
        deps: [HttpClient],
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: createTranslateLoader
      }
    })
  ],
  providers: [MyService]
})
export class MyFirstModule{}
```

**MySecondModule**

```js
registerLocaleData(_default, "fr");

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MySecondModuleComponent,
    ...
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MyMaterialModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    ClickOutsideModule,
    MyStore2Module,
    MyStore3Module,
    AngularSplitModule.forChild(),
    HighchartsChartModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        component: MySecondModuleComponent,
        path: ""
      }
    ])
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: LOCALE_ID,
      useValue: "fr-FR"
    }
  ]
})
export class MySecondModule{}
```

Comment: You could try moving the first path to the end of the list of routes.

Comment: @Edric moving the first path ({[...] pathMatch: "full" [...]}) still firing the error

Comment: Are you sure this is the code that causes problems? There is reference to the "MySecondModule" as a component in MySecondModule code.

Comment: @kvetis yeah it was a typo sorry, i offuscated the names

Comment: I think it may be related to sax.js because I use xml2js and jszip but I don't know ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

A coworker imported sax without npm and that caused xml2js and jszip to conflict over this library.

I installed sax via npm and removed the manual import and it is working now.

Comment: I am having a similar issue, any suggestions?
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'PagesModule' before initialization
    at Module.PagesModule , message: 'Cannot access 'PagesModule' before initialization'}